# Brightness at Magic Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, highlights

Does [Magic Keyboard](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MLA22B/A/magic-keyboard-british-english) have keyboard brightness feature? If so how to enable/adjust it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple Magic Keyboard does not have key illumination like the MacBook [Pro] and iPad Magic Keyboard do.

Comment: Do you know why? It seems previous version has it, no?

Comment: Apple has never provided key illumination in its standalone Mac keyboard peripherals.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but this would be very handy to have

Comment: No argument there :)